Why does my PyTorch DataLoader only use one CPU core despite setting num_workers>1?
I am trying to fine-tune BERT for a multi-label classification task (Jigsaw toxic comments). I created a custom dataset and DataLoader as follows:
class CustomDataSet(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self,
                 features: np.ndarray,
                 labels: np.ndarray,
                 token_max: int,
                 tokenizer):
    
        self.features = features
        self.labels = labels  
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.token_max = token_max
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self,
                    index: int):
        comment_id, comment_text = self.features[index]
        labels = self.labels[index]

        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            comment_text,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.token_max,
            return_token_type_ids=False,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            return_tensors='pt')

        return dict(
            comment_text=comment_text,
            comment_id=comment_id,
            input_ids=encoding['input_ids'].squeeze(0),
            attention_mask=encoding['attention_mask'].squeeze(0),
            labels=torch.Tensor(labels))

and I use the following tokenizer:
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

then I create my dataset using the custom class, and the corresponding dataloader:
train_dataset = CustomDataSet(X_train, y_train, tokenizer=tokenizer, token_max=256)
train_loader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, num_workers=16, persistent_workers=False
)

My model is the following:
class MultiLabelBERT(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_labels):
        super(MultiLabelBERT, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", torch_dtype=torch.float16, attn_implementation="sdpa")
        self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, num_labels)
        self.classifier = self.classifier.to(torch.float16)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        pooled_output = outputs.pooler_output 
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
        return logits

first_BERT = MultiLabelBERT(6)

I first want to iterate through all batches of my training set and perform a forward pass:
for batch_idx, item  in enumerate(train_loader):
    input_ids = item['input_ids'].to(self.device)
    attention_mask = item['attention_mask'].to(self.device)
    labels = item['labels'].to(self.device)
    logits = first_BERT(input_ids=input_ids,
                        attention_mask=attention_mask)

Even though I set num_workers=16 in my DataLoader, it only uses one CPU core to load data onto my GPU. This significantly slows down the process. Here’s what I’ve tried:

Reducing the batch size.
Reducing the number of tokens (token_max).
Tokenizing the entire dataset beforehand to ensure the tokenizer isn’t causing the bottleneck issue.
When I comment out the forward pass, the DataLoader uses all CPU workers as expected. However, with the forward pass, the process seems to be bottlenecked.
I have the following gpu setup:

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.120                Driver Version: 550.120        CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P0            588W /  115W |       9MiB /   8188MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1285      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |

Has anyone an idea of what could cause this?
